# SFTP permissions issue for a user

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sftp

I have a user called dbsssftpadmin who is in the root group.
There is a directory called /media/pi that has read and execute permissions for the group root.

[image]

Yet in FileZilla when im connected via SFTP and try to view the directory /media/pi i get an error:
Error:  Directory /media/pi: permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

I don't know why.

I can see lots of other directories on the SFTP but not this particular one.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out some ACL permissions on the directory were restricting the permissions on it, I ran

```
sudo setfacl -m "u:dbssftpadmin:r-x" pi
```

and that gave the permissions i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To rule this out and although you are in a group that has root access, you can list the directory via sudo:

```
sudo ls -la
```